# Keyword args vs position only args

Tags: coding-style

I really like keyword arguments because it helps me see what the variable actually is... on the other hand, often these variables are not optional, and kwargs are by default optional. How do use keyword args for mandatory variables, in a clean way?

Comment: Non-keyword arguments with IDE support that displays the parameter-argument correspondence at the call site combines the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

If your language supports defining some arguments as mandatory, then simple use that support.

If your language does not provide support for marking an argument as mandatory, you will need to provide that support yourself.

Generally a guard clause (an `if` that tests for whatever the magic undefined state is), at the top of you function is the best way to achieve this. You could potentially wrap this in its own function/macro but I would hesitate as this generally makes it harder to read.